# Mockito: how to get a mock object when iterate a list?

Tags: mockito

```
@Mock
Object obj;

List<Obejct obj> objs;
```

How to get a mock object obj back when I iterate over `objs`?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/quick-tip-on-mockito-mocking-iterator/)

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason not to use a real `List` (e.g. it being necessarily large in a small unit test), use a real `List` and add mock objects into it. Java collections are well-defined and well-tested, so you shouldn't ever need to mock them.

Comment: That answer is very useful too https://stackoverflow.com/a/43067304/3800377

Answer (score 6):

Code:

```
@Mock
private Iterator<YourObject> iteratorMock;
//...
when(yourListMock.iterator()).thenReturn(iteratorMock);
when(iteratorMock.hasNext()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE,
    Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
when(iteratorMock.next()).thenReturn(yourMock1, yourMock1, yourMock2);
```

---

As you can see in the code, mocking the iterator is a very handy way to return different mocks for the second, third, e.t.c call.

This way you could also very easily have the second call throw an exception and the third call working again, being able to test that the exception of the second call would be handled for example and the third result would still be processed.

Using a real list is an option, but I think mocking is more powerful and the code is more condensed to what you actually need for a specific test.