# Junit test for Loop

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am teaching myself Junit testing and I am struggling to create a test for the following code

```
 private ArrayList<AirbnbListing> List;

   public int getAvgReviews(){
    int sums = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < List.size(); i++){
        AirbnbListing houses = List.get(i);
        if(houses.getPrice() >= fromValue && houses.getPrice() <= toValue){
            sums += houses.getNumberOfReviews();
        }
    }
    return (sums/getNoOfProperties());
}
```

Can someone help me out

Comment: what is `List`?

Comment: private ArrayList<AirbnbListing> List;

Comment: OK and what is the issue happening? Where is the test you are writing?

Comment: I do not know how to approach this sort of situation  with a loop, I can only do simple Junit tests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking a List and attempting to iterate over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067137/mocking-a-list-and-attempting-to-iterate-over-it)

Comment: I need to do a Junit test not Mock

Comment: What exactly are you testing? Show us the code of your test.

Comment: a few points to note: what error are you getting where are you facing problem. Also, `List` is not initialized and is this correct `sums/getNoOfProperties()`

Comment: You can use `@Before` to put data into your list, and then test it normally asserting the result depending on your list data

Comment: Before you do anything else, identify what test cases you want to test.  These will be things like - list is empty, list has one house with a price in the required range, list has one house with a price outside the required range, list has many houses in the required range; and so on.  You'll write a separate JUnit method for each one of these; and in each method, you'll create a list with the right properties, then call the method, then check that the result is what you expect.  I would advise you read up on the "arrange, act, assert" pattern for a good way to lay out your test methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your List is not initialized. You probably want to change your function to accept a list to start off with like

```
public int getAvgReviews(List<AirbnbListing> listings){ ... }
```

from there, we can write a JUnit as simple or complicated as we'd like. For example:

```
@Test
public void simpleTest1(){
    List<AirbnbListing> list = new List<AirbnbListing>();
    // populate your list here with test elements
    // ie list.add(new AirbnbListing(...)); as many as needed

    // now if your list is 3 elements long with review ratings of [4, 5, 6],
    // we would want to test the assertion that getAvgReviews(list) is equal to 5

    assertTrue(getAvgReviews(list) == 5);
    // ... more assertions here if needed
}
```